# Disable Caching for Python

Tags: python, caching

I want to test and compare the speed of two different file-opening approaches over a network using multi-processing. To really see if the network is the bottleneck, I want to disable caching of the relevant data for the python process or another method to force the python process to get its data via network and explicitly not from the cache. Clearing the cache is not an option as I am working on a multi-user environment where caching itself is essential.

Comment: the remote server may be doing paging layer caching. to test this right you would need to reboot both systems between tests and be sure nothing else is running on either and no other system is using that remote server. set up 2 test systems and do the test for each case after a fresh bootup.

Comment: @Skaperen: I'm pretty sure that the local server (on which I'm running my scripts) is doing the caching, as my read-times are way below the possible network-transfer rates. Shutdown is not really a practical option, as multiple users are working on this machines.

Comment: Building on @Skaperen: since you want to test the network, you may build two _virtual_ servers (e.g., VirtualBox instances), which you could then reboot to your heart's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved this specific problem by piping my filelist to another python process which interfaced with the bash to call the `cachedel` command from the `nocache` package. This is no pure pythonic solution, but it worked in my case.

```
import glob
import subprocess
filelist=glob.glob('/path/to/file/*.fileending')
for dat in filelist:    
    subprocess.call("cachedel "+dat, shell=True)
```

Nevertheless, if caching itself is the timing bottleneck, it's a better idea to disable caching for the python process itself by running

```
nocache python
```

with the `nocache` package installed.